# Ac Adapters Pri & Sec ratings what can I use?

Tags: ac, adapter

I am a complete novice and know very little about this so please stick with me.

I have a set of lights that came with an AC adapter that is now faulty. On the adapter it has:

- Pri: 230V-240V ~50Hz.
- SEC: 24V ~850mA Max 20.4VA

I have another adapter which works the set but this has the following:

- Pri: 230-240V - ~50Hz
- SEC: 24V ~ 300mA Max - 7.2VA

As this is lower rated and works is it safe to use or have I got it all around the wrong way and it is unsafe to use because it is a lower rating?

I can't seem to find any replacement adapter to buy that matches the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right, the replacement part is not strong enough.

What you have to match is :

- The input voltage must be compatible with your country (here 230-240v ~50hz )
- The output voltage must be the same: (here 24v)
- The output kind: DC or AC. For AC you sometime have a symbol "~" written next to the output voltage. It must be the same.
- The output current must be greater or equal to the original (here 850mA)

Comment: Ok thanks, so even though the output of 300ma on the new one powers the lights it isn't safe to use. Is this because of the circuitry inside the adapter wont be able to handle it? Oh and the new one does have "~" before the 300ma if that makes a difference to an answer.

Comment: Would a  24v~ 1200ma Max 28.8va be suitable? @Blup1980

Comment: Yes it's ok. 1.2A is greater than 850mA.